# Outlook - changing the preview of tasks when mouse hovers

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

In Outlook 2016, I have the Task pane on (View ribbon -> To-Do Bar -> Tasks).

If I hover the mouse over any task in the pane, I get a 'preview', which includes some obvious and some irrelevant (for me) information. An example of irreleveant is what the Outlook Data File is.

Is there a way to customise what this list/preview shows?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no built-in option in Outlook to customize the fields in the mouse over preview of tasks. You may submit a feedback via [Outlook uservoice forum](https://outlook.uservoice.com/).